# Center align stack content in xamarin foms xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to align stack layout center to grid cell , but not able to achieve, Please look into this code and let me know if I have done any wrong alignment.

I want to place 2 labels center horizontally and vertically inside a stacklayout and the stack should be fill and expand in grid cell.

Please give some suggestions from your side.

```
      <Grid>

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>

          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f39c12" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Fill"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeCommand}" CommandParameter="Yes"/>

            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>


            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" InputTransparent="True">
              <Label Text="{StaticResource SmileIcon}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFont}" Margin="4,8,4,0" FontSize="32" TextColor="Red" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label >
            <Label x:Name="lbl_like" Font="Medium" Text="Like" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,4,0,4" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2ecc71"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,8,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Un_LikeCommand}" CommandParameter="No" />

            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" InputTransparent="True">
            <!--<Image x:Name="img_dislike" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"  Source="sad.png" InputTransparent ="true" Margin="0,4,0,4"></Image>-->
            <Label Text="{StaticResource SadIcon}" HeightRequest ="40" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFont}" Margin="4,8,4,0" FontSize="32" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>

            <Label x:Name="lbl_dislike" Font="Medium" HeightRequest ="40" Text="Dislike" FontAttributes="Bold" 
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>

        </Grid>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code: instead of `StackLayout` I used a `Grid` for the two layouts. It will work fine.

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

        <BoxView Color="#C0C0C0" HeightRequest="1" Margin="16,8,16,8" />

        <Grid>

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


          <Grid BackgroundColor="#f39c12" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8,0,0,8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width=".60*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeCommand}" CommandParameter="Yes"/>                

            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>                


            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{StaticResource SmileIcon}" HeightRequest="45" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFont}"  
                   FontSize="24" 
                   TextColor="White"
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                 
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            
            <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lbl_like" HeightRequest="45" Font="Medium" Text="SUPPORT" 
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

          </Grid>


          <Grid BackgroundColor="#2ecc71" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,8,8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width=".55*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Un_LikeCommand}" CommandParameter="No"/>                

            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>      
          

            <Label Text="{StaticResource SadIcon}" HeightRequest="45" Grid.Column="0"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFont}" 
                 FontSize="24" 
                   TextColor="White"
                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"></Label>

            <Label x:Name="lbl_dislike" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="45" Font="Medium" Text="OPPOSE" 
              FontAttributes="Bold"
              HorizontalOptions="Start"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

          </Grid>

        </Grid>

      </StackLayout>
```